# Size of char array is bigger than number of elements passed to initialize it

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c-strings, initializer-list

for arrays of type int or double, if the size of the array is bigger than the number of elements provided when the array is initialized (like a list), the rest of the elements in the array are defaulted to 0 right?

What happens when I initialize a character array with less elements than the size I provide? Like

```
char ch[10] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

Are the rest of the elements assigned any value? Or is it just garbage in memory?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/857132 they will be 0.

Comment: @Howard Wang  They are zero-initialized.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  Are you talking about int/double arrays? Or char arrays?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19

Comment: @HowardWang See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration

```
char ch[10] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

is equivalent to this declaration

```
char ch[10] = { "hello" };
```

that in turn is equivalent to the following declaration

```
char ch[10] = "hello";
```

and all these declarations are equivalent to the following declaration

```
char ch[10] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', };
```

That is elements of the array that do not have explicit initializers are implicitly zero-initialized.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. **If an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:**

...

> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;

and

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
>   initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
>   previously listed initializer for the same subobject;151) **all
>   subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
>   implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.